# Can we use Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem here?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f_n(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+x^{\tfrac{n}{\ln(n+3)}}}$.

I'm trying to show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int \dfrac{1}{1+x^{\tfrac{n}{\ln(n+3)}}} d\mu = \int \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{1}{1+x^{\tfrac{n}{\ln(n+3)}}} d\mu $.
I'm not sure if I can use the dominated convergence theorem here, because of the $\ln$ .

But here are some steps I've done:

Notice that

$f_n(x) \leq \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ for $n \geq 4$.

Take $g(x) =\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. Then we have $g \in L^1 $ (not sure about this step ).

Even if we can use the DCT, I'm not sure what $f$ would be.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ for $|x|\ge 1$ and $g(x)=1$ for $|x|\lt 1$, so $g(x) \in L^1$ can be used.  The limit is $f(x)=1$ for $|x|\lt 1$ and $f(x)=0$ for $|x|\gt 1$.  $f_n(1)=\frac{1}{2}$ not important.

Presume: $d\mu =dx$.

Comment: So we can use DCT here right? Bout what about the case $n<4$? Do we find a different bound, and use DCT separately?

Comment: You are looking for the limit as $n\to \infty$, so $n\lt 4$ is irrelevant.